# Using EF Code First, how to auto populate HashedPassword column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this entity :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Admins
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've already ignored `Password` property inside the entity configuration using Fluent API, so it won't be mapped.

But i want `HashedPassword` to be automatically populated whenever i create a new record or update it.

The `HashedPassword` value is taken from the hashing of `Password` property.

I really can't get my head around it to have `HashedPassword` auto-populated each time i create a new record or update `Password` of the existing one. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code inside the password setter.

E.g

```
public class Admins
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            HashedPassword = HashingMethod(_password);
        }
    }
}
```

You might not even need the getter.

Comment: Seeing as the point of hashing passwords is to make them not recoverable, the getter in fact makes no sense at all, not does persisting `Password`

Comment: im trying figure out why have both a password and a hash field. The use of hash password yes.  Stored in the password field.